# EAP-TTLS and EAP-TLS in RADIUS: Which is more accepted?

Tags: tls, radius

From what I understand:

[EAP-TTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5281) forces the RADIUS server to identify itself to a client with a certificate, but optionally a client to the server. All information about an end-user is encrypted through a tunnel.

[EAP-TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5216) forces the RADIUS server and the client to identify themselves with a certificate. The end-user's name is exposed in cleartext.

Assuming this is correct;

Is it possible to force a TTLS configuration to authenticate both sides? If so, does that not simply make it objectively better than TLS?

Is the fact that TLS exposes usernames incredibly relevant on a private network?

In general, which is more accepted as "the way to do it"?

Comment: usernames tend not to be classified as private or protected information

Comment: @schroeder I figured it's a privacy concern nonetheless.

Comment: Why did you edit the question title? This question isn't primarily about exposed usernames.

Comment: "accepted" in what way?